# MacBook fails to connect to Wi-Fi after it has been asleep for some time

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, sleep-wake

My MacBook Pro running macOS 12.2.1, fails to connect to any Wi-Fi network after it has been asleep for some time.

I open my laptop assuming it will be connected still, which it is not, then when I go to reselect the network it should already be connected too, it connects for a couple seconds then disconnects.
I have to restart my MacBook just for it to hold it's connection.

I'm assuming this is a software bug, does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see that on some networks my MBP is slow to connect to Wi-Fi after wake, on others it’s near instant. Usually the fix is to flip Wi-Fi off then back on again, rather than reboot. Have you tried this? Have you tried to see whether this happens to all networks or just a specific one, to rule out some issue with the router?

Comment: sorry, yes forgot to mention I have tried switching it off and on before reboot, I have tried multiple routers/networks